# History of the `/// <reference />` syntax in *TypeScript*

Tags: javascript, xml, reference, typescript

*TypeScript* has a way to include code from other files using the following syntax:

```
/// <reference path="./your/path" />
```

I am interested in:

1. Where is this coming from?
2. Who came up with this syntax?
3. Why tripple-slash comment? Is it used somewhere else as well?
4. Are there any other 'meta-comments' like this (in this format)?
5. Why use *XML* syntax (I mean in JavaScript, in 2015)?

Comment: resharper has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is this coming from?

Its coming from a javascript `references` method. History is documented here : http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs

> Are there any other 'meta-comments' like this (in this format)?

In TypeScript there is `amd-dependency` and `nolib` but I don't recommend using *ANY* of these options. You mostly don't need to know about these :) Note: Tsconfig.json is your friend : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

Comment: So basically it is the Microsoft *ad-hoc-non-standards-proprietary* thing that got borrowed from *Visual Studio* by the *TypeScript* team?

Comment: Yes. Most standards are proprietary before they become standards :)